# Reduce Memory From UIwebView Iphone after Page Loaded

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, uiwebview

I created one app for iphone based on uiwebview. but when i load
website on it, the app keep increase memory.

```
www.google.com + 5 Mb
www.google.news + 2 Mb 
www.google.com + 5 Mb (total 12 Mb)
```

But I don't want to do this situation, How to reduce the memory.
Especially my question is,How to reduce the memory from uiwebview
after page was already loaded. Thanks

Comment: Hi Thomas I already updated the question

Comment: Please provide us with some code so we can better understand your problem.

Comment: hi atrljoe, actually there's just very simple code. use the 

@property(nonatomic,assign)UIWebView *mainView;
and using NSURLRequest for normal webpage .. www.google.com

very simple, but memory is't keep growing up.
refresh the same page also still increase the memory

Comment: So are these links triggered by different actions in your app?